# An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found when reading from the JSON reader

Tags: sharepoint, powerquery

[image]

I'm working through a flow which will:

1. Create libraries based off a spreadsheet
2. Add a choice column with choices
3. Finally make some changes to
   the view, which is where things get stuck.

The main issue is, since I have to make so many libraries (well over 100+), we have to use a specific document library template for each. Since I can't find a way (I don't think there is a way) of making libraries using Power Automate which uses a library template, I've had to try and make the library again myself. Hence the extra columns.

The below code tries to see if a document in a library is marked as a record, has any retention label applied. If not, it goes in the WiP view. I will then make one which does the opposite and if it has retention, put it in the "Records" view.

Here is the code I am using:

```
   {

  "__metadata": {

    "type": "SP.View"

  },

  "Title": "WiP",

  "Aggregations": {

    "GroupByFieldsXml": "<FieldRef Name='CAT' />"

  },

  "ViewQuery": "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="_ComplianceTagWrittenTime" /></IsNotNull></Where>",

  "RowLimit": 100,

  "ViewFields": {

    "ViewFields": [

      "Title",

      "CAT",

      "Status",

      "Modified",

      "Editor"

    ]

  },

  "DefaultView": true

}
```

I keep getting this error however:

```
{

    "statusCode": 400,

    "headers": {

        "Pragma": "no-cache",

        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",

        "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=03653a5ff26f7e0adf0cd33338b896ea4ee4856ba3918ba0940d9b1fda36f29c;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-ukw.azconn-ukw-001.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=03653a5ff26f7e0adf0cd33338b896ea4ee4856ba3918ba0940d9b1fda36f29c;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-ukw.azconn-ukw-001.p.azurewebsites.net",

        "x-ms-request-id": "e83cb9a0-20ad-6000-b4e6-e9568774096a",

        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",

        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",

        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",

        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",

        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",

        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",

        "Date": "Sat, 03 Jun 2023 14:20:37 GMT",

        "Content-Length": "475",

        "Content-Type": "application/json",

        "Expires": "-1"

    },

    "body": {

        "status": 400,

        "message": "An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.\r\nclientRequestId: 988fe6f3-b416-4ff6-9d2d-1792062288c3\r\nserviceRequestId: e83cb9a0-20ad-6000-b4e6-e9568774096a",

        "source": REDACTED

        "errors": [

            "-1",

            "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"

        ]

    }

}
```

Any ideas?